# alarm is getting created everytime in xamarin.android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

i am trying to create a repeat alarm in `Xamarin.android` and this alarm is being triggered from the `Xamarin.Form` using the dependency service.

the problem is whenever i am triggering alarm from `Xamarin.Forms` its getting created everytime even if i have check which confirms that whether alarm is previously set or not. so in this case `isSchedulerOn()` is always returning false.

[Referece code for Alarm](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/part_3_-_viewing_running_services_and_stock_service_example/)

here is my code of `Xamarin.Form` , i am calling this function from `App.cs`

```
    DependencyService.Get<ISyncService>().startScheduler();
```

here is my code of `Xamarin.Android`

```
public  class SyncScheduler : ISyncService
    {
        private Intent syncServiceIntent;
        private  AlarmManager syncAlarmManager;
        private  PendingIntent syncPendingIntent;
        private int REQUEST_SYNC_SCHEDULE = 200;
        private long SYNC_SCHEDULER_INTERVAL = 30 * 1000;
        private readonly String TAG ="SyncScheduler";


        public void startScheduler()
        {


            if (!isSchedulerOn())
            {

                 syncServiceIntent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(SyncService));


                 syncAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);


                 syncPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(Android.App.Application.Context, 
                    REQUEST_SYNC_SCHEDULE, 
                    syncServiceIntent,
                    PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

                syncAlarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.Rtc, DateTime.Now.Millisecond, SYNC_SCHEDULER_INTERVAL, syncPendingIntent);
                Log.Error(TAG, "Sync: Scheduler created " );

            }
            else
            {

                Log.Error(TAG, "Sync: Scheduler Already Running " );
            }



        }
        public bool isSchedulerOn()
        {

            if (syncServiceIntent != null)
                return PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Android.App.Application.Context, REQUEST_SYNC_SCHEDULE, syncServiceIntent, PendingIntentFlags.NoCreate) != null;
            else return false;

        }

    }
```

Comment: `if (syncServiceIntent == null)` should be `if (syncServiceIntent != null)`

Comment: that was a typo and the problem still persist , i have edited the question though